# How do I keep my java program from running out of memory?

Tags: java, memory, arraylist

I'm writing a java program to scan folders with tens of thousands of high def images and pull some metadata from them. I already have the program working very well, except that it can only scan folders with about 100 images before giving an out of memory error. While I might be able to increase the maximum memory allocation (haven't really looked into it yet), that kind of a solution wouldn't be ideal because I'd need about 10 gigs of RAM to run the program, by my calculations.

I'm interested in how I could rewrite the following segment of code so that it doesn't use up as much memory when it runs.

```
    ArrayList<File> imageFiles = new ArrayList<File>(); 

    ...

    // Create an ArrayList of image sets, and add the image files to those sets, but 
    // don't convert them to BufferedImage objects until the sets themselves are processing.
    ArrayList<ImageSet> groupedFiles = new ArrayList<ImageSet>();
    for (File image : imageFiles) {
        int caseNumber = Ops.getCaseNumberFromFilename(image.getName());
        boolean foundMatchingCase = false;
        for (ImageSet i : groupedFiles) {
            if (i.caseNumber == caseNumber) {
                foundMatchingCase = true;
                i.addImageToSet(image);
            }
        }
        if (!foundMatchingCase) {
            Log.write("Creating new set for image " + image.getName(),
                    Log.STANDARD);
            ImageSet newSet = new ImageSet(caseNumber);
            newSet.addImageToSet(image);
            groupedFiles.add(newSet);
        }
    }
```

If additional context is necessary, [the source for the entire program is on my github](https://github.com/twtduck/NeuroImageAnalysis). (The code above is from src/threads/ImageProcessingThreadA.java.)

Thanks for whatever ideas you guys might have.

Comment: There's no way that you'll be displaying tens of thousands of images or even thousands of them, and so you'll want to look into using some type of mechanism to cache the information that is not immediately needed to disk, and swapping information on and off of disk to the program.

Comment: Share the calculation too. Why do you keep the metadata in memory ? Use an embedded SQL database